# How to run JQuery code only when user is outside textarea

Tags: jquery, textarea, blur

I want to run the code bellow only when user is outside textarea:

```
$(document).on('keydown', function(e){
    if (e.which == 37) {
        mySwiper.swipePrev();
    }
    if (e.which == 39) {
        mySwiper.swipeNext();
    }
});
```

This is what I use to certify user is leaving textarea:

```
$('textarea').bind('blur', function() {
    $(this).css({
        'background-color':'#E18B6B'
    });
});
```

Any help will be a joy. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can check before firing the event if the text area is in focus.

```
$("textarea").is(":focus");
```

To extend your code:

```
$(document).on('keydown', function(e){

    if (e.which == 37 && !$("textarea").is(":focus")) {
        mySwiper.swipePrev();
    }
    if (e.which == 39 && !$("textarea").is(":focus")) {
        mySwiper.swipeNext();
    }

});
```

Comment: In my case I want to run the code only when the user is outside textarea... This will prevent arrow navigation when user is typing someting inside textarea...

Comment: I added `!`(not) to the code to check if the text box is not in focus. 
Onblur event is triggered only when the user clicks the text box once and then clicks somewhere else.

Answer (score 1):

Just confirm that the event.target isn't a textarea.

```
$(document).on('keydown', function(e){
    if ( $(e.target).is("textarea") ) {
        return; // exit early
    }
    if (e.which == 37) {
        mySwiper.swipePrev();
    }
    if (e.which == 39) {
        mySwiper.swipeNext();
    }

});
```